# Why do some flex items not shrink as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have two sets of code, the first is a simple one which has an expected result, the second is unexpected.

In the simple code, I have a fixed height child `.fixed`. I also have flex child `.scrollable`.

When I shrink the screen, the .`scrollable` div first shrinks until its minimum height. Then the `.fixed` div shrinks, to accommodate the `50vh` that is assigned to `.parent`. Only when these two components are fully shrunk do they eventually overflow the `.parent` div. Even though `.fixed` has an assigned height, it does not have an assigned minimum height, so it makes sense that `.fixed` shrinks.

https://codepen.io/Sean713/pen/xxJZLeo

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 50vh;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}

.fixed {
  height: 40px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 90px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="fixed">
    I have fixed height
  </div>
  <div class="scrollable">
    <p>I am scrollable</p>
    <p>I am scrollable</p>
    <p>I am scrollable</p>
    <p>I am scrollable</p>
    <p>I am scrollable</p>
    <p>I am scrollable</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, in a more complex example, I expect the same pattern to occur but it does not.

In this code, my understanding is as follows:

We start to shrink the screen, `.blue` and `.green` flex. Inside `.blue`, `.orange` shrinks, as `.white` is fixed. Once `.orange` reaches its minimum height, I would expect `.white` to start shrinking as a minimum-height has not been assigned, but it does not. I do not understand why as this seems similar to the first code example.

Similarly, `.black` never shrinks as well, I do not understand why.

https://codepen.io/Sean713/pen/PoBZKbP

```css
.root {
  height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.blue {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.white {
  height: 50px;
}

.orange {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 30px;
}

.purple {
  flex: 1;
}

.green {
  height: 95%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.black {
  height: 40px;
}

.red {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 20px;
}


/* ________________STYLING_______________ */

.root {
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.blue {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.white {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.orange {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}

.purple {
  border: 3px solid purple;
}

.green {
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.black {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.red {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

````html
<div class="root">
  <div class="blue">
    <div class="white">
      I have fixed height (panel)
    </div>
    <div class="orange">I don't (cube)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="purple">
    <div class="green">
      <div class="black">
        <p>I am a fixed height header</p>
      </div>
      <div class="red">
        <p>I can scroll</p>
        <p>I can scroll</p>
        <p>I can scroll</p>
        <p>I can scroll</p>
        <!--         <p>I can scroll</p>
        <p>I can scroll</p>
        <p>I can scroll</p>
        <p>I can scroll</p>
        <p>I can scroll</p>
        <p>I can scroll</p>
        <p>I can scroll</p>
        <p>I can scroll</p> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

```
````

I have tried research both this forum and elsewhere but have not been able to understand why.

Comment: I works like you want to, when you add a height (in vh) to .blue and .purple (or .green also works)

Comment: Why do I need to add heights to those? Since they're already `flex: 1;` shouldn't they try to fill their container? And the container has a vh set.

Comment: I thought so too but for some reason it doesn't. That seems to be the only difference between the two codepens

Comment: I see- that seems a bit weird though since I'm not able to know what the height of those elements in vh is.

Comment: Using `%` also seems to work

Comment: It doesn't really have the desired effect- and I can't know the % either (if I knew the % I could just as easily calculate the vh since the root container is sized via vh)